# Install DisplayLink on Linux Elementary OS

Tags: release-hera

I'm trying to use my wavlink 4k USB docking station: https://wavlink.com/en_us/product/WL-UG69PD1.html with Linux.

I tried the following: https://github.com/AdnanHodzic/displaylink-debian, DisplaLink option now shows up but says "cable unplugged"

https://github.com/AdnanHodzic/displaylink-debian

[image]

Comment: What kernel version are you running ('uname -r' from a command line to find out)?

Comment: @Mudito, it says: 5.3.0-28-generic

Comment: @ShaneKmdid you find a solution to this?

Comment: nope. I gave up :(